# Google Data Studio Data Connectors - All versions listed in the data source list

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I created a Google Data Studio Data Connector called "wiki views". In the process, I had 18 versions. And I only want to keep the last version. So I deleted all the other versions in Deployments window.

[image]

Now I want to create a report using the data connector I just created.

Here is the Edit page of the new Data Studio Report

[image]

In the right drop down list of the data source I can select. I can see there are 18 "wiki views" listed, and I even don't know which item is for which version. It should be just the last version listed there.

1. How can I only keep one "wiki views" (last version) in the available data source to select from?
2. In the process of developing the data connector, I have to deploy to test, right? so I will have many versions which are not working or I don't want to keep, I already delete them in the "deploy window", it will be very messy that all the versions in my developing process will show up here even they are deleted.
3. Where I can find a page that list all the data connectors I created and to manage them (like delete etc)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [Data Sources](https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/navigation/datasources) to manage possible data connectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data Sources and Apps Script versions are separate entities. Deleting versions from Apps Script will not delete data sources created from that version of code, however, they will no longer work since the code cannot be found. [Data Sources](https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/navigation/datasources), as mentioned by Александр Ермолин is the right place to go if you want to remove existing data sources.

As a tip, naming a data source after creation is a good way to keep track of which one is which. See [Edit a data source](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7178497) for details on doing this.